# How to search item using key in object and update that value into the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
var replaceArr = ['A','J','Q',10,2];
    
var originalArr = [{A:0},{2:1},{3:2},{4:3},{5:4},{6:5},{10:9},{J:10},{Q:11},{K:12}];
```

As per the snippet I have two array:
`replaceArr` and `originalArr`

I want to compare the `replaceArr` with the `originalArr` and get the key value from there and replace into the `replaceArr`.
Means after replacing the `replaceArr` would be `== [0,10,11,9,1]`

In Advanced Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simple use `map` and `find` from array prototype

```js
var replaceArr = ["A", "J","Q",10,2]
    
var originalArr = [{A:0},{2:1},{3:2},{4:3},{5:4},{6:5},{10:9},{J:10},{Q:11},{K:12}];

replaceArr = replaceArr.map(v => originalArr.find(obj => obj[v] !== undefined)[v]);
console.log(replaceArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can club all the different objects in originalArr and then search for replaceArr values in it like below

```js
var replaceArr = ['A','J','Q',10,2]
    
var originalArr = [{A:0},{2:1},{3:2},{4:3},{5:4},{6:5},{10:9},{J:10},{Q:11},{K:12}]

let arrWithOneObject = Object.assign(...originalArr)

let result = replaceArr.map(d => arrWithOneObject[d])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript array foreach function

```
originalArr.forEach((val) => {
  var replaceIndex = replaceArr.indexOf(Object.keys(val)[0]);
  if (replaceIndex >= 0) {
    replaceArr[replaceIndex] = val[Object.keys(val)[0]];
  }
});
```

Comment: it displays wrong result `[0, 10, 11, 10, 2]`, the correct result should be `[0,10,11,9,1]`

Comment: seemed to be working on my side
var replaceArr = ['A','J','Q','10','2']
    
var originalArr = [{A:0},{2:1},{3:2},{4:3},{5:4},{6:5},{10:9},{J:10},{Q:11},{K:12}]
originalArr.forEach((val) => {
  var replaceIndex = replaceArr.indexOf(Object.keys(val)[0]);
  if (replaceIndex >= 0) {
    replaceArr[replaceIndex] = val[Object.keys(val)[0]];
  }
});console.log(replaceArr);

Answer (score 0):

```js
var replaceArr = ['A','J','Q','10','2']   
var originalArr = [{A:0},{2:1},{3:2},{4:3},{5:4},{6:5},{10:9},{J:10},{Q:11},{K:12}]

originalArr.forEach((item)=>{
  let property = Object.keys(item)[0];
  let indexOfproperty = replaceArr.indexOf(property);
  if(indexOfproperty !== -1){
    replaceArr[indexOfproperty] = item[property]
  } 
})

console.log(replaceArr)
```